# How to stack consecutive APOC statements in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I stumbled on the following syntax for setting labels during a `LOAD CSV` operation in Neo4j with Cypher.  It works but I don't understand *why*, and all of the following modifications break it:

- Removing any of the `YIELD` statements
- Changing `YIELD node` to `YIELD node2` or any other name on the 2nd and 3rd `YIELD` statements
- Removing any of the repeated `WITH n,row` statements between the `YIELD` statements
- Adding `UNION` between the calls (at least, I couldn't get it to work)

Can anyone enlighten me?  I'm a relative newcomer to Cypher and APOC and I'd love to understand how to make repeated APOC calls properly.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///myfile.csv' AS row
MERGE (n:Person{id:row.ID,name:row.Name}) 
WITH n,row
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), [row.Title,row.Position] YIELD node
WITH n,row
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), split(row.Roles, ',')) YIELD node 
WITH n,row
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), split(row.Aliases, ',')) YIELD node
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [CALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/), [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/), and [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/).

Here are answers to your specific questions:

- When you `CALL` a procedure that can return results, you generally must also specify a `YIELD` for at least one of the procedure's result fields and use the exact field name. You can use [SHOW PROCEDURES](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/listing-procedures/) to get the signature of a procedure, which includes its result fields. For example, to get the signature of `apoc.create.addLabels`:

  ```
  SHOW PROCEDURES YIELD name, signature
  WHERE name = 'apoc.create.addLabels'
  RETURN signature
  ```
- `YIELD` must specify at least one of the result field name(s) used in the procedure's signature. You cannot use arbitrary names, although you can immediately use `AS` to rename a field (e.g., `YIELD officalName AS foo`).
- Cypher does not permit multiple `YIELD`s to produce the same variable name (in the same scope). To get around this, you can use `AS` to rename such variables. For example, this should work:

  ```
  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///myfile.csv' AS row
  MERGE (n:Person{id:row.ID,name:row.Name}) 
  WITH n,row
  CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), [row.Title,row.Position]) YIELD node AS _
  CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), split(row.Roles, ',')) YIELD node AS __
  CALL apoc.create.addLabels(id(n), split(row.Aliases, ',')) YIELD node
  RETURN node
  ```

  (*Also FYI: [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) changes the set of variables that are in scope. If any subsequent clauses need a variable, then a `WITH` clause must specify that variable.*)
- As documented, a [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/union/) "combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set". You cannot just put `UNION` between arbitrary clauses.

Comment: Thank you!  Interesting that the signature specifies a particular variable name.  I guess I still don't understand why the first `WITH` statement doesn't carry over to the subsequent calls, since nothing changes.  And from the examples in the help file, it looks like UNION would require RETURN statements--is that right?

Comment: I updated my third bullet to cover your situation. Also, `UNION`ed subqueries must `RETURN` the same result fields.